# how can replace "\" from a string like "c:\inetput\myfolder\" for "/"

Tags: javascript

I have a string that is returned by the backend made in c# (I do not have access to the backend, so I need to solve this problem):

```
var string="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder\BackDeploy\MachineLearning\exported_dataset"
```

I need replace all the `\` for `/`.

of this way, I have many errors.

```
string.replace("\","/");
```

How can do it?.

the result should be:

```
"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/myfolder/BackDeploy/MachineLearning/exported_dataset"
```

Comment: `string.replace("\\","/");`, escape slash `\`

Comment: Do you _really_ have that string, or do you have `var string = "c:\\inetpub\\...`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe The server returns me that string. "c:\inetpub\"..

Comment: @ildflue not works.... replace all \ for ''

Comment: @yavg That's probably different to it being hardcoded in a string like that...

Comment: are you doing this with node.js ? I'm pretty sure there's something in there to deal with Windows paths in the [Ppath module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html).

Comment: @Touffy A server in c# returns that path..

Comment: `string.replace(/\\/g, "/");` because `replace(someString, ...)` will only replace the first occurance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the backslash to have it considered as a literal, not as an escape character. That applies both to your input literal, and to the pattern for `replace`.

In addition to that, to replace *all* occurrences, not just the first, you should use a regex with the `g` modifier as pattern:

```js
var string = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\myfolder\\BackDeploy\\MachineLearning\\exported_dataset"

var out = string.replace(/\\/g, "/")

console.log(out)
```

Comment: thanks but... tI do not have access to the backend. the string is returned with only \ not \\

Comment: Well, you only have to escape it if you are dealing with a string literal as it is the case here. If you get it from the backend, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

replace method just replace the first matching element and the replace all doesn't exist, the fastest way to achive this is with split and join

```js
var string = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\myfolder\\BackDeploy\\MachineLearning\\exported_dataset"
//you have to add two times backslash because is a special character
    var out = string.split('\\').join('/') 

    console.log(out)
```